# MyStile theme custom top menu woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

I want to customize woocommerce theme MyStile.

How do I change the top menu "item" (items) to Stück?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This can be changed by:

- Go to Appearance -> Editor and find the file `theme-woocommerce.php`
- Open that file and find this line

  ```
  echo '<span class="contents">' . sprintf(_n('%d item', '%d items', $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_contents_count(), 'woothemes'), $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_contents_count()) . '</span>';
  ```
- Change "item" and "items" to "Stück".
- Save the file and it should be changed.